# A ZFC example of a Menger space which is not Scheepers

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, selection-principles

$\Omega$: The collection of all [$\omega$-covers](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0166864195000674) of a space $X$. An open cover $\mathcal U$ of $X$ is said to be $\omega$-cover if $X\notin\mathcal U$ and for each finite $F\subseteq X$ there exists a $U\in\mathcal U$ such that $F\subseteq U$.

1. A space $X$ is said to have the [Menger property](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0166864195000674) if for each sequence $(\mathcal U_n)$ of open covers of $X$ there exists a sequence $(\mathcal V_n)$ such that for each $n$ $\mathcal V_n$ is a finite subset of $\mathcal U_n$ and $\{\cup\mathcal V_n : n\in\mathbb N\}$ covers $X$.
2. A space $X$ is said to have the [Scheepers property](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0166864195000674) if for each sequence $(\mathcal U_n)$ of open covers of $X$ there exists a sequence $(\mathcal V_n)$ such that for each $n$ $\mathcal V_n$ is a finite subset of $\mathcal U_n$ and $\{\cup\mathcal V_n : n\in\mathbb N\}\in\Omega$ or $\cup\mathcal V_n=X$ for some $n$.

A space $X$ is said to be Menger (respectively, Scheepers) if $X$ has the Menger (respectively, Scheepers) property. It is well known that every Scheepers space is Menger but the coverse is not true (see [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/347178683_Finite_powers_and_products_of_Menger_sets)). We are looking for a ZFC example of a Menger space which is not Scheepers (here, it means without any additional set-theoretic assumption, is there a Menger space which is not Scheepers?).

Comment: Where exactly in the paper you reference is the "Scheepers property" defined?  (It's most certainly not defined under that name).  Also, in  your definitions you probably meant $\bigcup\{\mathcal V_n : n\in\mathbb N\}$ instead of $\{\cup\mathcal V_n : n\in\mathbb N\}$?

Answer (score 8):

It is consistent that every Menger space is Menger in all finite powers (at least for "nice" enough spaces), see the paper  [Products of Menger spaces in the Miller model](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.10385.pdf)
(L. Zdomskyy, Advances in Mathematics 335 (2018), 170–179.)

Spaces with all finite powers Menger are $S_\text{fin}(\Omega,\Omega)$, and in particular Scheepers.

So, there is no ZFC example of a Menger space that is not Scheepers.